# What is the differerce between calling a function with await and without it?

Tags: dart, async-await

I'm coming from a language that uses threads instead of async/await and I'm confused as to what the purpose of await is.

Everyone says that the `await` keyword tells the program to wait until an `async` function completes, but in the following code I don't use `await` in front of the `doSmth()` calls, yet, they still pause the execution:

```
import 'dart:io';

Future<String> _loadFromDisc() async {
  sleep(Duration(seconds: 1));
  return 'idfromdisc';
}

Future<String> _fetchNetworkData(String id) async {
  sleep(Duration(seconds: 1));
  return 'somedata';
}

class ProcessedData {
  ProcessedData(this._data);
  String _data;
}

void doSmth() async {
  print('doSmth started');
  sleep(Duration(seconds: 1));
  print('doSmth finished');
}

Future<ProcessedData> createData() async {
  doSmth();
  doSmth();
  print('calling loadFromDisc');
  final id = await _loadFromDisc();
  print('calling fetchNetworkData');
  final data = await _fetchNetworkData(id);
  print('done');
  return ProcessedData(data);
}

void main() {
  createData();
}
```

I mean, it makes sense, it would be weird if all the functions were executed immediately, but why do we need `await` if the code works the same way anyway?

Comment: `doSmth` pauses execution because it calls `sleep`, which pauses execution in the isolate.  `await` doesn't matter in your example because you don't really do anything asynchronous.  Try replacing `sleep` with `await Future.delayed(...)` instead, and then you'll see a difference. Additionally, as written, `await doSmth()` in principle won't work since `doSmth` doesn't return a `Future`.

Answer (score 1):

Picture this you have an asynchronous code
What asynchronous is  it let's you move to other code if the one it's performing takes to long that is to prevent freeze and low performance
And you have here to fetch from a very big data
But you need this data afterwards
If you do it without await it will be a promise and you will have an error or undesired result so you have to till it to await for this fetch then continue hope i made it clear